# Sobre blank projects utilizando o git

Tags: git, projeto-de-software

Estamos querendo aproveitar um modelo de projeto para os nossos futuros projetos. Como se fosse um *blank project*.

Estavámos tentando *forkar* os projetos, mas não deu muito certo. Qual solução vocês utilizam?

PS.: Estamos utilizando o Gitlab internamente.

Comment: Qual foi o problema com o fork?

Comment: Tipo, temos um projeto base que queremos utilizar ele nós próximos projetos. Mas não conseguimos fazer vários forks desse mesmo projeto. Nós tinhamos pensado em algo como ter duas duas origens, cada projeto. Sendo uma apontada para o projeto base, e outra para o projeto corrente.

Comment: O que é possível fazer é clonar o projeto e subí-lo em outro repo, mudando o remote dele. Acho que é a solução mais simples pro problema de vocês. Junto a isso criar um upstream do projeto original, para quando houverem updates que sejam puxados do projeto "raíz"...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Tinhamos conversado sobre isso também, mas achamos que teria outra alternativa. De qualquer forma, irei conversar com o pessoal aqui e esperar mais alguém dar alguma dica.

Answer (score 1):

## Modelo de branching

O que é conhecido por modelo de branching é imprescindível. Não tem ligação exatamente com Gitlab, Github ou outro. Independente do serviço que você usa, não existe uma única proposta de modelo de branching, ou a melhor proposta, até porque depende de várias variáveis pertinentes ao projeto em questão.

Isto não significa que você não terá alguma orientação inicial. E o melhor não é repetir aqui o que outros sugerem, como a Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops, ou opinião de terceiros https://medium.com/@grazibonizi/the-best-branching-model-to-work-with-git-4008a8098e6a.

Se não entendi errado, você pode iniciar com a sugestão simplificada da Microsoft, fornecida acima, e estendê-la, se vir necessidade.

Comment: Muito interessante seu comentário. Hoje, onde eu trabalho, criamos um repositório com o nosso projeto modelo. Toda vez, quando iniciamos um novo projeto, temos que mudar a origem e apontar para o novo repositório. Queria saber se existia outra opção

Comment: Pela sua fala suponho que o esforço correspondente é mínimo. Se é o caso, e está atendendo vocês, talvez não exista motivo para mudança.